# Error in running a python script in command prompt

Tags: python, pycharm, robotframework

I am running the below line in command prompt with the below code but my script is not being initiated from `pycharm`:

I am checking the directory where my script exists:

```
K:\PycharmProjects\workshop-robot>dir
 Volume in drive K is USER_SHARES
 Volume Serial Number is 569B-2F04

 Directory of K:\PycharmProjects\workshop-robot

28.07.2015  11:37    <DIR>          .
28.07.2015  11:37    <DIR>          ..
23.07.2015  10:12    <DIR>          .idea
27.07.2015  17:37               837 Abbott.robot
24.07.2015  14:20               752 Allianz.robot
24.07.2015  16:08               748 diageo.robot
24.07.2015  16:08               756 freenet_ag.robot
24.07.2015  16:09               770 friesland_campina.robot
28.07.2015  11:37           209.277 log.html
28.07.2015  11:38            12.261 output.xml
28.07.2015  11:37           212.337 report.html
29.07.2015  17:45    <DIR>          resources
28.07.2015  11:37            30.228 selenium-screenshot-1.png
28.07.2015  11:37            30.228 selenium-screenshot-10.png
28.07.2015  11:37            30.228 selenium-screenshot-2.png
28.07.2015  11:37            30.228 selenium-screenshot-3.png
28.07.2015  11:37            30.228 selenium-screenshot-4.png
28.07.2015  11:37            30.228 selenium-screenshot-5.png
28.07.2015  11:37            30.228 selenium-screenshot-6.png
28.07.2015  11:37            30.228 selenium-screenshot-7.png
28.07.2015  11:37            30.228 selenium-screenshot-8.png
28.07.2015  11:37            30.228 selenium-screenshot-9.png
24.07.2015  12:03               760 testcase.robot
              19 File(s)        740.778 bytes
               4 Dir(s)  343.376.748.544 bytes free
```

Here I am initiating the command to run my script:

```
K:\PycharmProjects\workshop-robot>c:\Python27\Scripts\pybot.bat testcase.robot

K:\PycharmProjects\workshop-robot>c:\Python27\Scripts\pybot.bat Abbott.robot

K:\PycharmProjects\workshop-robot>c:\Python27\Scripts\pybot.bat Abbott.robot

K:\PycharmProjects\workshop-robot>c:\Python27\Scripts\pybot.bat Abbott.robot

K:\PycharmProjects\workshop-robot>c:\Python27\Scripts\pybot.bat testcase.robot

K:\PycharmProjects\workshop-robot>c:\Python27\Scripts\pybot.bat testcase.robot
```

Could you please tell why is my script not initiated

Comment: Good, now decrypt the question, so we can help you.

Comment: actually my script iitself is not intiating after this,,,thats why am unable to run.once i click enter it returns back the prompt with -(K:\PycharmProjects\workshop-robot>)

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little unclear, however try running your script using cmd with pybot again. The command should/could look something like:

```
pybot \PycharmProjects\workshop-robot.robot
```